# Evaluation time is always 0.23 s

Tags: performance-tuning, timing

Following the instructions in [this documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/DisplayTheTimingOfAnEvaluationInANotebookWindow.html), I'm setting `EvaluationCompletionAction -> "Show Timing"` in the option inspector so that *Mathematica* prints out the evaluation time in the status area. The problem is that the evaluation time is quickly printed over by another evaluation time which is really irrelevant to me, 0.23 s, whatever that means. I've probably changed too many settings to be able to agree with what the guy in the video in the link I provided. Anyone know what to change so that *Mathematica* does not overwrite the evaluation time with this useless .23s?

I suspect .23s is the time it takes to print the output. But then how can I remove this setting?

EDIT: I see that people have a hard time understanding the problem at hand. The most basic example is the following.

I write in mathematica (with timing and everything else "on"):

"How are you?"
Then I see in the lower left window that it takes x amount of time to evaluate my stupid question but this x is very quickly overwritten by another time y. So obviously there are two timers involved here. I am more interested in the former (x) while the latter is some stupid thing M10 likes to print...it's probably the time it takes M10 to print on screen "How are you?".

Hope this made things clearer.

Cheers.

Comment: What did you do with the time you saved by writing Mathe instead of Mathematica? Also you should post your code before anyone helps.

Comment: Is there a short name /nickname for Mathematica? What code should I post ?

Comment: @Faq *Mathematica* is not really so long that it needs a short name; you should post whatever code you are using that visualizes the timing you discuss in your post. Otherwise we have no idea what you are doing and can't help you.

Comment: From his link it looks like there is no code.  It's a notebook setting that displays a timing from the last evaluation in the front end.

Comment: I have followed the instructions given in the reference from the question and tested the result using `Nest[3.5 # (1 - #) &, 1./Pi, ct]`, where I have varied `ct`.  I cannot reproduce the problem described by in the question.  This suggests an error in the OP's unpublished code.

Comment: Good point @bbgodfrey.  In my answer I am just assuming that the OP's error will become obvious once they explicitly call `Timing`, but perhaps I should wait to see what they are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Can we all agree that from now on we say MX instead of Mathematica version X? I have M10, what do you have and so on?

Comment: @Faq: What version, exactly, do you have? I suspect 10.0.0 or 10.0.1, which had the behavior you describe. It was fixed in 10.0.2 and later.

Comment: @Faq A common abbreviation for Mathematica is MMA ([ref](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/635/definition-of-mma)). That said MarcoB is completely right; Mathematica not long enough that you can't take the time to spell it out.

Comment: There are at least four (five depending on how you count)  ups and downs in the name Mathematica:  Ma The  Ma Ti Ca...it's too long to say it in my head when I write that's why I don't like it.

Comment: @Brett I'll check the version, perhaps I can update and solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation for `Timing`.  I've never used this particular option for a notebook that you linked to, but if you are concerned about the `Timing` of a particular evaluation then just wrap the expression of interest in the `Timing` statement.

```
Timing[Nest[#^2 &, 1, 10^6]]
Out[]= {0.031250, 1}
Timing[Nest[Timing[#[[2]]^2] &, {Null, 1}, 10^6]]
Out[]= {2.437500, {0., 1}}
```

In the first example the time it takes to square something a million times is 0.03125s. In the second case the time it takes to square something *once* is 0s and the time it takes to square something *and* calculate the timing a million times is 2.4375s.

Comment: `Timing` requires forethought, and becomes part of the actual flow of data (and so needs to be worked around when using `%`, etc..) The interface option Faq is trying to use provides (ideally) and easy way to answer the question "How long did that just last calculation take?" without any additional effort or overhead. It is limited to only *the* most recent evaluation, but I still find it incredibly useful multiple times per day.